# How to listen for a command on bash?

Tags: bash, listener, webhooks, slack-api

I am trying to write to a webhook whenever a specific command is run in bash. For example, when `ls` is called, run a script.

More specifically, when the command `spark` is ran, I want to write to a slack channel using their webhooks.

Comment: @vikingsteve, ew. Aliases don't work from scripts; they don't work for executions from non-shell executables; they don't allow you to do conditional logic (as you could with shell functions); etc. Also, `.sh` extensions are bad form -- see rant at https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful.shtml, or the word of the freenode #bash bot at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: see `shopt -s expand_aliases` - but that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: @cdarke, yes, I'm aware that it exists, and prefer to ignore that fact. When someone asks a question where aliases are actually the right approach (very occasionally, a case exists where textual prefix expansion is actually useful; I think I've seen three in my career, though I can't right now remember what they were), I'll bring it up.

Answer (score 0):

Put a wrapper earlier in the PATH. Let's say that `spark` is in `/usr/bin`. If your users' PATHS have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, then you can do this in `/usr/local/bin/spark`:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "${_SPARK_WRAPPER_DONE}" ] || send-to-slack-here "$@"
export _SPARK_WRAPPER_DONE=1
exec /usr/bin/spark "$@"
```

...where `send-to-slack-here`, of course, is your code to send a message to Slack.

You could also move `/usr/bin/spark` to `/usr/bin/spark.real` and put your wrapper in the original executable's place.

---

If you control `.bashrc`, you could also use a shell function (though this will work in fewer scenarios):

```
spark() {
  send-to-slack-here "$@"
  /usr/bin/spark "$@"
}
```

Comment: Why the `_SPARK_WRAPPER_DONE` guard? In case `/usr/bin/spark` re-execs itself by bare name/path lookup?

Comment: @EtanReisner, paranoia, pure and simple. I'd rather showcase a good practice in a situation where it's useless and have someone leverage it later when it's useful than to have a misapplication of my advice here lead to an endless loop later.